# UISearchController and MvvmCross

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want add search logic for my application (IOS8). I have simple `MvxTableViewController` and display my data by `UITableViewSource`. Here is:
...controller:

```
    MvxViewFor(typeof(MainViewModel))]
    partial class MainController : MvxTableViewController
    {
        public MainController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }


        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();


            // make background trasnsparent page 
            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            this.TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;

            this.SetBackground ();

           (this.DataContext as MainViewModel).PropertyChanged += this.ViewModelPropertyChanged;
        }

        private void SetBackground()
        {
            // set blured bg image

        }

        private void ViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var viewModel = this.ViewModel as MainViewModel;
            if (e.PropertyName == "Title")
            {
                this.Title = viewModel.Title;
            }
            else if (e.PropertyName == "Topics")
            {
                var tableSource = new TopicTableViewSource(viewModel.Topics);
                tableSource.TappedCommand = viewModel.NavigateToChildrenPageCommand;

                this.TableView.Source = tableSource;
                this.TableView.ReloadData();
            }
        }
```

I read about search in IOS and choosed `UISearchController` for IOS8 app. But I don't understand, how I can add this controller to my view :(
I found sample from Xamarin (TableSearch) - but they don't use `UITableViewSource` and I don't understand what I should do with this. 
I tried add controller:

```
this.searchController = new UISearchController (this.searchTableController) 
{
       WeakDelegate = this,
       DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false,
       WeakSearchResultsUpdater = this,
};

this.searchController.SearchBar.SizeToFit ();
this.TableView.TableHeaderView = searchController.SearchBar;

this.TableView.WeakDelegate = this;
this.searchController.SearchBar.WeakDelegate = this;
```

what should I do in this.searchTableController? Do I need move my display logic there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The "searchTableController" should be responsible for the presentation of search results.

[Here is the test project (native, not xmarin) which help you understand.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)

The searchController manages a "searchBar" and "searchResultPresenter". His not need add to a view-hierarchy of the carrier controller. When user starts typing a text in the "searchBar" the "SearchController" automatically shows your SearchResultPresenter for you.

Steps:
1) Instantiate search controller with the SearchResultsPresenterController.

2) When user inputs text in the search-bar you should invoke a your own service for the search. Below a sample of code..

```
#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;

    if (searchString.length > 1)
    {
        // TODO - call your service for the search by string
        // this may be async or sync
        // When a data was found - set it to presenter
        [self.searchResultPresenter dataFound:<found data>];
    }
}
```

3) In the search presenter need to reload a table in the method "dataFound:"

```
- (void)dataFound:(NSArray *)searchResults
{
    _searchResults = searchResults;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I saw this sample, It is analogy of xamarin samle ([TableSearch](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8%5CTableSearch/)) .
But in these samples don't used UITableViewSource. 
I don't understand, how can I combine and how should I edit my logic for correct  search work.

Comment: @NikitaBondarenko added the explanations

Comment: I understand. I need create new `TableViewController` for displaying search results. It is should be simple controller with list of items and override default methods for displaying (`RowsIsSection `and `GetCell `etc) or youself `UITableViewSource` with method for updating this source.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some advice on how to use the `UISearchController` with Xamarin.iOS.

1. Create a **new class** for the results table view subclassing `UITableViewSource`. This is gonna be the view responsible of displaying the results. You need to make the items list of that table view **public**.

   ```
   public List<string> SearchedItems { get; set; }
   ```
2. In your main `UIViewController`, create your `UISearchController` and pass your result table view as an argument. I added some extra setup.

   ```
   public UISearchController SearchController { get; set; }

   public override void ViewDidLoad ()
   {
       SearchController = new UISearchController (resultsTableController) {
           WeakDelegate = this,
           DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false,
           WeakSearchResultsUpdater = this,
       };

       SearchController.SearchBar.SizeToFit ();
       SearchController.SearchBar.WeakDelegate = this;
       SearchController.HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;

       DefinesPresentationContext = true;
   }
   ```
3. The best way to add the search bar to your UI in term of user experience, in my opinion, is to add it as a `NavigationItem` to a `NavigationBarController`.

   ```
   NavigationItem.TitleView = SearchController.SearchBar;
   ```
4. Add methods to perform the search in the main `UIViewController`:

   ```
   [Export ("updateSearchResultsForSearchController:")]
   public virtual void UpdateSearchResultsForSearchController (UISearchController searchController)
   {
       var tableController = (UITableViewController)searchController.SearchResultsController;
       var resultsSource = (ResultsTableSource)tableController.TableView.Source;
       resultsSource.SearchedItems = PerformSearch (searchController.SearchBar.Text);
       tableController.TableView.ReloadData ();
   }

   static List<string> PerformSearch (string searchString)
   {
       // Return a list of elements that correspond to the search or
       // parse an existing list.
   }
   ```

I really hope this will help you, good luck.

Comment: I understand. I need create new `TableViewController` for displaying search results. It is should be simple controller with list of items and override default methods for displaying (`RowsIsSection `and `GetCell `etc) or youself `UITableViewSource` with method for updating this source.
Thanks.

Comment: That is correct. 
Note: `UITableViewSource` is just a helper that combines both `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.